# Counterexample of limsup of sets and measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

On page 163 in Wheeden-Zygmund, it is proved that for a nonnegative additive set function $\phi$, $\ \overline{\lim} \phi(A_n) \le \phi(\overline{\lim} A_n)$ for any sequence of measurable functions $(A_n)$, where $\overline{\lim}$ denotes the lim sup. I know that, intuitively, volume can disappear at infinity (example below), so $\phi(\underline{\lim} A_n) \le \underline{\lim} \phi(A_n)$ is intuitive to me. However, $\ \overline{\lim} \phi(A_n) \le \phi(\overline{\lim} A_n)$ does not make intuitive sense to me. I cannot find a problem with the proof in the text, but I also have found what may be a counterexample.

Let $A_n = [0, n] \times [0, \frac{1}{n}] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and let
\begin{equation}
    \phi(A)=
    \begin{cases}
      m(A) &\text{ if} \quad m(A) < \infty \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It follows that $\phi$ is a nonegative additive set function on measure space ${(\mathbb{R}^2, M)}$, where $M$ is the Lebesgue measurable sets.

Now, note that $\overline{\lim} \phi(A_n) = 1$, since $\phi(A_n) = 1$ for every $n$. However, $\overline{\lim}A_n = \mathbb{R}$, so $\phi(\overline{\lim}A_n) = 0$, contradicting $\ \overline{\lim} \phi(A_n) \le \phi(\overline{\lim} A_n)$.

Comment: Your $\phi$ is not additive. $\phi([0,1]^2 \cup [1,+\infty)^2) = 0 \neq 1 + 0$.

Comment: Apart from that, check the book again, there _must_ be some further conditions, otherwise the claim is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just take $\phi$ to be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The lim sup is $\mathbb{R}$ which has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer. The correct statement about an inequality of limit superiors is called the "reversed Fatou's lemma", you can see a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma), just took as functions characteristic functions for the sets

Comment: Or, maybe a "non-negative additive set function" is not allowed to attain the value $+\infty$ in that book. If that is the case, the necessary condition is given by the definitions.

Comment: @Masacroso That explains it.  What's missing is the function $g$. You could make your comment an answer, in my opinion.